# How ignore some condition in where clause according to third parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The select statement with current where clause is ok if **HasFilter = 1** otherwise the last two condition must be ignore. How can I complete my query?

```
ALTER   Procedure   [dbo].[spGetNotPrintedCards]
@FromDate   DateTime,
@ToDate     DateTime,
@HasFilter  Bit
As
    Select  CustomerName,
        Family,
        [ExpireDate],
        Track1,
        Track2,
        Track3,
        CVV2
        From    OfoghCardsRequest.dbo.CardRequests
        Where   Printed = 0 And
            CreateDate > @FromDate And
            CreateDate < @ToDate
```

Comment: For the sake of curiosity because I also learn that I want to know if my solution provides the appropriate response .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way, I think, is the following:

```
Select  CustomerName,
        Family,
        [ExpireDate],
        Track1,
        Track2,
        Track3,
        CVV2
        From    OfoghCardsRequest.dbo.CardRequests
        Where   Printed = 0 And (
            (@Hasfilter = 0 OR @Hasfilter IS NULL) OR
            (CreateDate > @FromDate And CreateDate < @ToDate))
```

If `@HasFilter` is not equal to 1, i.e. if `@HasFilter = 0` or `@HasFilter IS NULL`, then

```
((@Hasfilter = 0 OR @HasFilter IS NULL) OR 
 (CreateDate > @FromDate And CreateDate < @ToDate))
```

is always true, thus your where clause boils down to: `Printed = 0`

Comment: just a nitpicking, since your answer is the accepted one, you might handle NULL for @Hasfilter

Comment: @bummi you are right. For completeness, NULL has to handled as well

Answer (score 3):

You can use such condition:

```
Where   Printed = 0 And
        (
            (@HasFilter = 1 And CreateDate > @FromDate And CreateDate < @ToDate)
            Or @HasFilter <> 1
        )
```

Here you use `AND` to combine conditions if `@HasFilter = 1`, otherwise condition `@HasFilter = 0` will be used which will ignore 2 other conditions

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamic query. Something like

```
declare @sql varchar(300);
set @sql = 'Select  CustomerName,
        Family,
        [ExpireDate],
        Track1,
        Track2,
        Track3,
        CVV2
        From    OfoghCardsRequest.dbo.CardRequests
        Where   Printed = 0 ';

if(@HasFilter = 1)
set @sql = @sql + 'And CreateDate > @FromDate And
            CreateDate < @ToDate'

exec(@sql);
```